# Complex join in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

I hope you can help me because my brain is bleeding right now :

To explain specifically :

On my website, I have a table versus. A versus is a vote between two images.

The table versus contain 2 field : **id_pic1** for the first pic and **id_pic2** for the second.

Each versus is linked to a **comments** table (**id_versus**) and a users table (**id_versus also**).

Last thing is : **each pic on each versus is link to a table vote (id_pic,id_versus)**.

I used to use cakePhP so contain made the query easy, but now, with CI, my brain is stuck on freeze.

If someone can help with leads on the general query I should make, I'll be grateful for life.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : 
Here's a simplified view of the db :

**versus**
id_pic1
id_pic2
id_author

**users**
id

**pics**
id

**comments**
id_versus
id_author

**vote**
id_versus
id_pic

Comment: What do you want to "ask" from the DB? It's mysql?

Comment: I want an object versus who contains $versus->comments, $versus->pic1, $versus->pic2 etc... Everything who is related to my versus. I know it's just one big query, with cakePhP, contain helped a lot (with his limited recursivity), but in CI, I must say I have no clue on how to write it down.

Answer (score 0):

This is how multiple joins are done in CI, Make your according to this

```
       $this->db->select('aw.id,awt.title,aw.price,aw.email,aw.is_shop as star_shop,aw.video');
        $this->db->from('artworks aw');
        $this->db->join('artwork_translations awt', 'aw.id = awt.artwork_id');
        $this->db->join('languages l', 'l.id = awt.language_id');
        $this->db->where('l.code', $language_code);
        $this->db->where('awt.status', 1);
        $this->db->where('aw.artist_id', $artist_id);
        $this->db->order_by('aw.id DESC');

        $sub_categories = $this->db->get();

        return $sub_categories->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table layout seems to be incomplete or it lacks info.
How are the tables connected to each other?

Also, what data are you trying to select and by which parameters?
Is the authord of a versus also a user which can be found in the users-table?

Do you want to pick a versus (parameter = id_versus) and select all data from that?

```
function showDataFromVersus($versusToShow) {
    $this->db->select('*');                                  // select all data
    $this->db->from('versus');                               // get data from table versus
    $this->db->join('pics', 'pics.id = versus.id_pic1');     // get data pic2
    $this->db->join('pics', 'pics.id = versus.id.pic2');     // get data pic1
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = versus.id_author'); // get data versus author
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id_versus = versus.id');  // select comments
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = comments.id_author');  // get data comment author
    $this->db->join('vote', 'vote.id_versus = versus.id');   // get votes
    $this->db->where('versus.id', $versusToShow);
}
```

This function accepts a versus id and returns all data linked to it.

The MySQL-query for this would be

```
SELECT *
    FROM versus
        JOIN pics ON pics.id = versus.id_pic1
        JOIN pics ON pics.id = versus.id_pic2
        JOIN users ON users.id = versus.id_author
        JOIN comments ON comment.id_versus = versus.id
        JOIN users ON users.id = comments.id_author
        JOIN vote ON vote.id_versus = versus.id
    WHERE versus.id = 1
```

The result will contain a lot of columns and I haven't tested wether CodeIgniter can work with the double column names.
There will also be quite a lot of 'double' rows. For each comment and each vote, there will be a new row with the same versus-data

```
| ------------- VERSUS --------------| - PIC1 - | - PIC2 - | - USERS - | --------- COMMENT --------- | ------ VOTE ------ |
| id | id_pic1 | id_pic2 | id_author | id | ... | id | ... | id | .... | id_versus | id_author | ... | id_versus | id_pic |
```